# HTML5 videos doesnt play in android

Tags: android, jquery, html, video

I am trying to add a html5 video in my website however the video doesnt play in Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 (Android 4.1.1). I used videojs as my plugin. To make sure that the device really can play those videos, I visited this (http://praegnanz.de/html5video) website and try to play they're each video but unfortunately it didn't. I wonder what cause the issues and I am hoping for any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

please check whether your stock browser supports html5
Try installing chrome or Opera web browser

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you must check, depending on the web browser you're using :

- Video format: Some browsers accept H264/MP4 but not WebM (or vice versa).
- autoplay: Some browsers (like Chrome for Android) do not respect the autoplay attribute, to save bandwith. On these browsers, an explicit user action is required (like a click).